# API deployed from localhost to github throw 404 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest

I started my first api project and tested it in local host "http://localhost:3000/api/" and everything works on the browser.

But after deployed to github, and access "https://trily84.github.io/API_timestamp/api/" it throws 404 error.

The index.html is in the root folder "https://trily84.github.io/API_timestamp". The idea is to click on the 2 hyperlinks in the html as api working examples.

I'm new to api and backend stuff so I'm obviously missing something?

```
//index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
<a href="api/2015-12-25">[project url]/api/2015-12-25</a><br>
<a href="api/1451001600000">[project url]/api/1451001600000</a>
</html>
```

```
//server.js

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
app.use(express.static('public'));

// http://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/api/:datestring?', (req, res) => { code block })

var listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why "https://trily84.github.io/API_timestamp/index.html" works? but not "http://localhost:3000/index.html" (it throws Cannot GET /index.html error)?

Answer (score 1):

you cant expect github to launch your express server. it wont.

github.io only serves static files.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Raphael PICCOLO said, Github only serves static files. You cannot run a Nodejs application on Github. You can use [this](https://glitch.com/) instead. I deployed my freecodecamp assignments on glitch and it worked. You can see this [link](https://ddkhoa-fcc-apims-timestamp.glitch.me/)

> I don't understand why "trily84.github.io/API_timestamp/index.html" works? but not "localhost:3000/index.html"

In your folder, you have the `index.html` file and Github serves this file (and it does nothing with your nodejs code). The error in localhost is because you don't have "/index.html" route and the file `index.html` is not in `public` folder. You can move `index.html` in `public` folder to see what happens :). In that case, this part isn't necessary anymore.

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

(This will handle "/" path, you have the content of index.html when visit http://localhost:3000)

Comment: So when we access your page at "https://ddkhoa-fcc-apims-timestamp.glitch.me/", it doesn't actually open index.html, it actually just route to index.html through server.js? and how does it know to execute server.js in the beginning?

Comment: Yes, the `app.get("/")` route is executed and gives index.html. For glitch, I added the "main" property in package.json to let it know which file is the main entry of the application, like this: "main": "server.js".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments all. I ended up deployed to Heroku and it works!